# How to freeze a column using Excel Interop API?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, excel

How do I freeze a column in .NET using Excel's Interop API. Don't care what .Net language you write code in. I tried:

```
Public Sub FreezeColumn(ByVal FileName As String, ByVal SheetName As String, ByVal RangeName As String)

    Dim oExcel As Excel.Application = Nothing
        Try
            oExcel = New Excel.Application
            oExcel.Visible = False
            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(RangeName) Then Exit Sub
            oExcel.Workbooks.Open(FileName, False, True)
            oExcel.DisplayAlerts = False

            For Each wsheet As Worksheet In oExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
                If wsheet.Name = SheetName Then
                    wsheet.Range(RangeName).Select()
                    oExcel.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next

            oExcel.Save()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw
        Finally
            If Not IsNothing(oExcel) Then
                If Not IsNothing(oExcel.ActiveWorkbook) Then
                    oExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close(SaveChanges:=True)
                    ProcessHandler.ExcelDispose(oExcel)
                    oExcel = Nothing
                End If
            End If
        End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to activate the sheet before you can Freeze panes.

Add

```
wsheet.Activate
```

Before

```
wsheet.Range(RangeName).Select()
```

**See this Test Sample**

```
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Public Class Form1   
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) _ 
    Handles Button1.Click
        Dim oExcel As New Excel.Application

        oExcel.Visible = True

        oExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\book1.xls", False, True)
        oExcel.DisplayAlerts = False

        For Each wsheet As Excel.Worksheet In oExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
            If wsheet.Name = "Sheet1" Then
                wsheet.Activate()
                wsheet.Range("A1").Select()
                oExcel.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Your code worked and then I changed oExcel.Visible = False and it doesn't work any more.

Comment: If you have `oExcel.Visible = True` then it will work else it will not because you need the window to be active.

Comment: I can't make visible = True. Any way to achieve this with Visible = False?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. You need to activate it. What you could do is move the `.visible=true` just before freezing and `.visible=false` after freezing